# Sum of a numeric columns into specific ranges and counting its occurrences

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am quite new to programming field of Python.
I have a dataset which needs to be modified. I tried few methods for sum part but I dont get the exact results.

Dataset : [My data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AZeQ.png)

Requirements:

1. To categorize the debit and credit values into the following ranges/bins :
   a) 2000-4000
   b) 5000-8000
   c) 9000-20000
2. The sum of debit should be for **20 days** period like
   if the transaction happened on 2020-01-01 then
   the sum of credit should be from 2020-01-01 to 2020-01-20
3. I also want the record of occurrences i.e
   the number of times the value from the bins lies in the category

Required Result  : [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpPFx.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpPFx.png)

The code I tried for credit values:

```py
    EndDate = BM['transaction_date']+ pd.to_timedelta(20, unit='D') 
    StartDate= BM['transaction_date']
    
    dfx=BM
    dfx['EndDate'] = EndDate
    dfx['StartDate'] = StartDate
    dfx['Debit'] = dfx.apply(lambda x: BM.loc[(df['transaction_date'] >= x.StartDate) & 
                                                (BM['transaction_date'] 
                                                   <=x.EndDate),'Debit'].sum(), axis=1)
```

Code1-[image: result3]
Code2-[image: result4]

error : [image: Error]

Comment: Those 3 colored categories(D column ) are grouped by names (or id).
Like , a person named USG made 3 debit transactions in the month August which totals to 16000(F column).
Now this 16000 lies in the Category C which represents  range ( 9000-20000)

Comment: The second coloured group(green-gray one) does not seem to be grouped by name

Comment: Correct. My mistake !

Comment: I have replaced that with the improved version.

Comment: But is it possible to get the sum using python?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a lot of functions and broke the problem into smaller tasks. Hope the comments make this understandable.

```
def sum20Days(df, debitORCredit):
    """
    Calculates the sum of all amount in the debitORCredit column of df looking 20 days into the future within df

    df: pandas DataFrame. Should already do groupby on name
    debitORCredit : String. Takes either debit or credit. Column names in the dataframe

    Returns:
    df: Creates a column sum_debit_20days, adds the sum amount and returns the final dataframe

    """
    df = df.copy()
    temp_df = df[df[debitORCredit]>0]
    dates = sorted(temp_df["transaction_date"].unique())
    curr_date = dates[0]
    date_20days = curr_date + pd.Timedelta(20, unit="D")
    i = 0
    while i < len(dates):
        date = dates[i]
        if date > date_20days:
            curr_date = date
            date_20days = curr_date + pd.Timedelta(20, unit="D")

        series = temp_df.loc[(df["transaction_date"]>=date)&(df["transaction_date"]<=date_20days), :]
        df.loc[max(df.loc[df["transaction_date"] == series["transaction_date"].max()].index), f"sum_{debitORCredit}_20days"] = sum(series[debitORCredit])
        new_i = series["transaction_date"].nunique()
        if new_i > 1:
            i = new_i+1
        else:
            i += 1

    return df

def groupListUsingList(inp, groupby):
    """
    Groups inp by list groupby
    inp: List
    groupby: List

    Example: inp = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], groupby=[3, 6] then output = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7]]

    """
    groupby = sorted(groupby)
    inp = sorted(inp)
    lst = []
    arr = []
    for i in inp:
        if len(groupby) > 0:
            if i <= groupby[0]:
                arr.append(i)
            else:
                if len(arr)>0:
                    lst.append(arr)
                arr = [i]
                groupby.pop(0)
        else:
            arr += inp[i:]
    if len(arr) > 0:
        lst.append(arr)

    return lst

def count_amounts_in_category(df, debitORCredit, category_info):
    """
    Based on the category assigned, finds the number of amounts belonging to that category
    Inputs-
    df: Pandas Dataframe. Grouped by name and only contains the transactions belonging to a single category calculation
    debitORCredit: String. Takes either credit/debit. Used to get column in df
    category_info: Dict. Contains the rules of categorization.

    Output-
    count: Float. Returns count
    """
    if debitORCredit.lower() == "debit":
        temp_df = df.loc[(df["debitorcredit"]=="D")]
    elif debitORCredit.lower() == "credit":
        temp_df = df.loc[(df["debitorcredit"]=="C")]

    if temp_df.shape[0] == 0:
        return np.nan
    category = temp_df.iloc[-1].loc[f"category_{debitORCredit}"]
    amount_range = category_info.get(category)
    count = temp_df[debitORCredit].apply(lambda x: 1 if x<=amount_range[1] and x>=amount_range[0] else 0).sum()
    return count

def assign_category(amount, category_info):
    """
    Assigns category based on amount and categorization rules

    Input - 
    amount: Float/Int. The amount
    category_info: Dict. Contains the rules of categorization.

    Ouptut - 
    Returns the String category based on the categorization rules
    """
    if pd.isna(amount):
        return np.nan    
    for k, v in category_info.items():
        if v[0]<=amount<=v[1]:
            return k
    return np.nan

category_info = {"A": (2000, 4000),
                "B": (5000, 8000),
                "C":(9000, 20000)}

debitORCredit = "debit"

new_df = pd.DataFrame()
#Groupby name, then for each date in a group, calculate the sum of debitORCredit amounts over the next 20 days
for group in df.groupby("name"):
    temp_df = sum20Days(group[1], debitORCredit=debitORCredit)
    new_df = pd.concat([new_df, temp_df])
new_df = new_df.reset_index(drop=True)

#Based on the 20 days sum, use the categorization rules to assign a category
new_df[f"category_{debitORCredit}"] = new_df[f"sum_{debitORCredit}_20days"].apply(lambda x: assign_category(x, category_info))

#After assigning a category, groupby name and later groupby each 20 day transaction to find the count of transaction that belong to category assigned to that group of transactions
for group in new_df.groupby("name"):
    #to groupby every 20 day transaction, we identified the last row of every 20 day transaction (ones which have a sum_debit_20days value) and split the group(a group from name groupby) on the last value in the index
    indices = groupListUsingList(inp=group[1].index, groupby=group[1][group[1][f"sum_{debitORCredit}_20days"].notna()].index)
    for index in indices:
        count = count_amounts_in_category(df=new_df.loc[index], debitORCredit=debitORCredit, category_info=category_info)
        new_df.loc[index[-1], f"count_{debitORCredit}"] = count
new_df
```

[image: Working Screenshot]

Comment: And it would really helpful if you could tell what "inp" list is ?

Comment: Line 15 
indices = groupListUsingList(inp=group[1].index, groupby=group[1][group[1][f"sum_{debitORCredit}_20days"].notna()].index)

I am getting an error at line 15 " 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable ". 
Its something related to sort() method, But I dont where to apply it though

Comment: I have added the snaps as Code 1 and Code2 in the post.

Comment: Did you define the `category_info`? Also check if `debit` column is int/float. What is the type error saying if you scroll down on the last screenshot

Comment: Yes, I have defined all the functions . 

error is : 'nonetype' object is not subscriptable in python
I have also added a screenshot of it

Comment: Looks like it's not able to get a `category` from `category_info` . Could be that category is `NaN` or something for which the rules aren't set. If you need any more help I'm at https://meet.google.com/gxi-twep-gzf

Comment: I have replaced a function with isnull(). And it works smoothly.